# Unexpected Tab key behavior in Datasheet form subdatasheet

Tags: ms-access

When I tab through records in my (datasheet) form, the tab key behavior is as expected; Focus moves to the next field, and then at the end of the fields moves to the next record. In forms where I have master-child subdatasheets, when the subdatasheet isn't expanded and the user tabs past the end of a record, focus moves to the next record. This is good / what I want. When a subdatasheet is expanded and the user tabs past the end of the master record, focus moves to the first field in the child subdatasheet. Again this is good / what I want.

What happens on the next tab key press is my issue. Rather than moving focus to the next field in the subdatasheet, focus goes straight to the next record in the master datasheet. I expect and want focus to go to the next field in the subdatasheet.

I have been playing with the tabstops and cycle properties on both the main form, subform, and subform control within the main form, and cannot come to a configuration where I get the behavior I desire.

Comment: I suspect focus does not go to the first field in the child Subdatasheet but to the entire Subdatasheet itself. You can probably catch that with the `On Got Focus` event on the form and manually move the focus to the first field.

Comment: Tried putting a Me.MyFirstControl.SetFocus in the OnGotFocus event, as suggested, and now when I tab into the subdatasheet I get a Runtime Error 2950 "Reserved Error". :/

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. Does not appear to be a programming issue. Something about design is not allowing the correct behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this now and thought I should log it here. Was a pretty stupid problem caused by an oversight on my part.

Basically, all of the controls on my subdatasheet were being set to locked and tabstop = false, in a procedure I have to apply control settings by control name. So I'd actually made those settings a while ago, forgotten, and then assumed that the user should be able to tab through them.

Obviously Access was hitting the subdatasheet control, going "no controls available to tab through here", and so immediately exiting the subdatasheet control.

When I was trying in code to set focus to any of the controls, the reserved error 2950 must've been because the controls weren't tab-stoppable.